# .htaccess specify end of URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the URL `/sub` to `/sub-folder/`, though it's not as easy as it may seem! This is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
^sub /sub-folder/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

The browser is instantly redirected to `/sub-folder/`, but then apparently this URL still falls under the `^sub` expression (the dash confuses the browser), so it keeps redirecting, ending with an error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

How can I in the .htaccess make browsers understand that the URL `/sub-folder/` is not the same as `^sub`?

Thank you!

Comment: Put it in brackets, see if it helps. ^sub /(sub-folder)/ [R=301,NC]

Comment: Also specify end of url to avoid redirect loop: ^/sub$ /(sub-folder)/

Comment: Brackets didn't work, but the $ sign did, thank you! Isn't this considered a hack though? Since $ is normally used for saving whatever comes afterwards for later use.

Comment: `$` in regex means end of input and that what you're doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like the problem wasn't with the hyphen. You needed to specify the end of input.

Just additional tip: put slash and question mark to account for slash or no-slash at the end of the url:

```
RewriteRule ^/sub/?$ /sub-folder/
```

This way both
http://domain.com/sub 
and
http://domain.com/sub/
will be caught by your rule.

Comment: I see. So if your URL doesn't end with slash then you have to manually specify end of input? Also, does the question mark always make the letter/sign before it conditional, or does it only with in combination of a slash?

Comment: Question mark indicates that preceding character is optional. You can for example rewrite HTML pages like "*.html?" - this way both *.html and *.htm will be caught. If you don't indicate end of input, anything beginning with "sub" will be caught. That's why you had a redirect loop, because "sub-folder" matches "sub". Hence, infinite loop.